# Mysql the reverse of a group_by statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following schema:
[image: db schema]

The concept goes like this:
We have sellers and buyers. Sellers create tasks and buyers initiate chats and start conversations. So a seller is able to have many chats with different buyers for a task (one chat per buyer and a buyer can initiate just one chat, but he can send many messages) and a chat will have many messages. The message has as an author_id which is either a seller or a buyer.

So I want to find two things (two queries):
One is I want to find all the tasks which doesn't have messages with author_id equals to tasks.seller_id (or don't have messages at all).

Second is, I want to find the reverse, tasks with at least one message with author_id equals to seller_id. The second one is following query ( thanks @bill-karwin ):

```
SELECT t.id, COUNT(*) AS sellerMessages 
FROM tasks AS t
INNER JOIN chats AS c ON c.task_id = t.id
INNER JOIN messages AS m ON m.chat_id = c.id
    AND t.seller_id = m.author_id
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING sellerMessages > 0
ORDER BY t.id;
```

How can I find the reverse?

**Update**

I've pasted a sql script with records to test: http://pastebin.com/KmMJjQsR
It creates 60 different task records with their messages and chats associations.

Which returns 31 tasks the above sql query and it is correct. I need to find the reverse of the above, which it will return the other 29 tasks.

**Creation script**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tasks`;

CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`seller_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `index_tasks_on_seller_id` (`seller_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `seller_id`)
VALUES
  (15788, 95157),
  (15789, 95158),
  (15790, 86270),
  (15791, 86270),
  (15792, 94260),
  (15793, 14354),
  (15794, 95160),
  (15795, 95161),
  (15796, 10786),
  (15797, 95162),
  (15798, 72740),
  (15799, 95163),
  (15800, 93159),
  (15801, 95165),
  (15802, 95168),
  (15803, 95170),
  (15804, 95173),
  (15805, 6983),
  (15806, 95175),
  (15807, 95177),
  (15808, 80037),
  (15809, 45066),
  (15810, 95180),
  (15811, 95181),
  (15812, 95182),
  (15813, 84020),
  (15814, 95156),
  (15815, 93418),
  (15816, 74020),
  (15817, 74020),
  (15818, 73604),
  (15819, 95190),
  (15820, 95188),
  (15821, 39132),
  (15822, 95191),
  (15823, 95192),
  (15824, 95196),
  (15825, 32979),
  (15826, 30104),
  (15827, 95198),
  (15828, 95200),
  (15829, 93974),
  (15830, 95201),
  (15831, 95202),
  (15832, 33487),
  (15833, 60076),
  (15834, 33487),
  (15835, 88081),
  (15836, 95204),
  (15837, 95205),
  (15838, 27527),
  (15839, 93055),
  (15840, 95209),
  (15841, 2297),
  (15842, 95211),
  (15843, 76806),
  (15844, 69400),
  (15845, 34273),
  (15846, 95214),
  (15847, 82877);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `chats`;

CREATE TABLE `chats` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`creator_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`task_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `chats` (`id`, `creator_id`, `task_id`)
VALUES
  (10754, 53058, 15788),
  (10767, 36414, 15788),
  (10778, 61359, 15788),
  (10759, 61359, 15789),
  (10770, 36414, 15789),
  (10961, 10541, 15790),
  (10777, 61359, 15792),
  (10819, 11835, 15793),
  (10766, 4631, 15795),
  (10791, 18461, 15795),
  (10823, 31111, 15795),
  (10874, 11649, 15795),
  (10994, 85902, 15795),
  (10769, 36414, 15797),
  (10776, 61359, 15797),
  (10919, 53058, 15797),
  (10771, 12815, 15798),
  (10775, 83339, 15798),
  (10811, 12745, 15799),
  (11211, 35416, 15799),
  (10793, 4631, 15800),
  (10833, 85902, 15800),
  (10816, 36414, 15802),
  (10806, 36414, 15803),
  (10801, 80049, 15804),
  (10818, 36414, 15804),
  (10824, 11835, 15805),
  (10802, 7240, 15806),
  (10822, 39871, 15806),
  (10838, 79168, 15806),
  (10817, 36414, 15807),
  (10918, 53058, 15807),
  (10809, 33051, 15808),
  (10843, 20435, 15808),
  (10803, 45069, 15809),
  (10804, 5093, 15809),
  (10814, 84699, 15810),
  (10844, 58098, 15810),
  (10847, 95206, 15810),
  (10849, 95105, 15810),
  (10853, 94009, 15810),
  (10854, 94009, 15810),
  (10855, 94009, 15810),
  (10856, 94009, 15810),
  (10857, 94009, 15810),
  (10858, 94009, 15810),
  (10859, 94009, 15810),
  (10860, 94009, 15810),
  (10894, 65435, 15814),
  (11057, 91171, 15815),
  (10975, 85902, 15816),
  (10812, 4631, 15817),
  (10841, 85115, 15818),
  (10903, 87971, 15818),
  (10980, 36414, 15819),
  (10886, 39393, 15821),
  (10825, 11835, 15824),
  (10871, 2919, 15824),
  (11194, 21322, 15824),
  (11137, 94553, 15825),
  (10831, 84932, 15826),
  (10836, 83339, 15826),
  (10839, 8532, 15826),
  (10840, 11967, 15826),
  (10913, 35573, 15827),
  (10983, 36414, 15827),
  (10878, 29425, 15829),
  (10952, 36414, 15831),
  (10845, 10511, 15832),
  (10941, 7240, 15832),
  (10872, 3154, 15834),
  (10897, 36414, 15835),
  (10917, 53058, 15835),
  (11045, 36902, 15835),
  (10879, 29425, 15836),
  (11114, 94682, 15836),
  (10900, 36414, 15837),
  (10846, 4631, 15838),
  (10850, 4631, 15839),
  (10848, 4631, 15841),
  (10852, 4631, 15842),
  (10851, 4631, 15844),
  (10864, 62822, 15845),
  (10889, 85115, 15847);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `messages`;

CREATE TABLE `messages` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`chat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`author_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `messages` (`chat_id`, `author_id`)
values
  (10754, 53058),
  (10767, 36414),
  (10778, 61359),
  (10759, 61359),
  (10759, 95158),
  (10770, 36414),
  (10770, 95158),
  (10961, 10541),
  (10961, 86270),
  (10777, 61359),
  (10819, 11835),
  (10819, 14354),
  (10766, 4631),
  (10766, 95161),
  (10791, 95161),
  (10791, 18461),
  (10823, 31111),
  (10874, 11649),
  (10994, 85902),
  (10769, 36414),
  (10776, 61359),
  (10919, 53058),
  (10775, 83339),
  (10775, 72740),
  (10811, 12745),
  (10811, 95163),
  (11211, 35416),
  (11211, 95163),
  (10793, 4631),
  (10793, 93159),
  (10833, 85902),
  (10833, 93159),
  (10816, 36414),
  (10806, 36414),
  (10801, 80049),
  (10818, 36414),
  (10824, 11835),
  (10824, 6983),
  (10802, 7240),
  (10802, 95175),
  (10822, 39871),
  (10838, 79168),
  (10838, 95175),
  (10817, 36414),
  (10817, 95177),
  (10918, 53058),
  (10809, 33051),
  (10809, 80037),
  (10843, 20435),
  (10843, 80037),
  (10803, 45069),
  (10804, 5093),
  (10814, 84699),
  (10814, 95180),
  (10844, 58098),
  (10844, 95180),
  (10847, 95206),
  (10847, 95180),
  (10849, 95105),
  (10849, 95180),
  (10853, 94009),
  (10853, 95180),
  (10894, 65435),
  (10894, 95156),
  (11057, 91171),
  (10975, 85902),
  (10975, 74020),
  (10812, 4631),
  (10812, 74020),
  (10841, 85115),
  (10841, 73604),
  (10903, 87971),
  (10903, 73604),
  (10980, 36414),
  (10980, 95190),
  (10886, 39393),
  (10886, 39132),
  (10825, 11835),
  (10825, 95196),
  (10871, 2919),
  (10871, 95196),
  (11194, 21322),
  (11194, 95196),
  (11137, 94553),
  (10831, 84932),
  (10836, 83339),
  (10839, 8532),
  (10839, 30104),
  (10840, 11967),
  (10913, 35573),
  (10913, 95198),
  (10983, 36414),
  (10878, 29425),
  (10878, 93974),
  (10952, 36414),
  (10845, 33487),
  (10845, 10511),
  (10941, 7240),
  (10872, 3154),
  (10872, 33487),
  (10897, 36414),
  (10897, 88081),
  (10917, 53058),
  (11045, 36902),
  (11045, 88081),
  (10879, 29425),
  (10879, 95204),
  (11114, 94682),
  (10900, 36414),
  (10900, 95205),
  (10846, 4631),
  (10846, 27527),
  (10850, 4631),
  (10850, 93055),
  (10848, 4631),
  (10852, 4631),
  (10852, 95211),
  (10851, 4631),
  (10851, 69400),
  (10864, 62822),
  (10889, 85115);
```

**Results:**

In one query (the one with the included `sender_id` on messages) there should be returned either `31` or the job ids

```
 15789,15790,15793,15795,15798,15799,15800,
 15805,15806,15807,‌​15808,15810,15814,15‌​816,
 15817,15818,1581‌​9,15821,15824,15826,‌​15827,
 15829,15832,15‌​834,15835,15836,1583‌​7,15838,
 15839,15842,‌​15844
```

and in the other query the result should be

```
 15841,15796,15825,15845,15809,15833,15843,
 15847,15813,15791,‌​15815,15792,15788,15‌​794,
 15797,15801,1580‌​2,15803,15804,15811,‌​15812,
 15820,15822,15‌​823,15828,15830,1583‌​1,15840,15846
```

or `29`.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry for the suggestion, I've updated my answer hopefully now it's ok.

Comment: And the desired result?

Comment: In one query (the one with the included sender_id on messages) there should be returned either 31 or the job ids `15789,15790,15793,15795,15798,15799,15800,15805,15806,15807,15808,15810,15814,15816,15817,15818,15819,15821,15824,15826,15827,15829,15832,15834,15835,15836,15837,15838,15839,15842,15844` and in the other query the result should be `15841,15796,15825,15845,15809,15833,15843,15847,15813,15791,15815,15792,15788,15794,15797,15801,15802,15803,15804,15811,15812,15820,15822,15823,15828,15830,15831,15840,15846` or 29.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find ... tasks with at least one message with
>   `author_id` equals to `seller_id`.

Your query in the question can be simplified a bit. There is no need for explicit `HAVING` filter, because `INNER JOINs` would do it. If you don't need count of messages, you can omit the `COUNT`.

```
SELECT t.id
FROM tasks AS t
INNER JOIN chats AS c ON c.task_id = t.id
INNER JOIN messages AS m 
    ON  m.chat_id = c.id
    AND t.seller_id = m.author_id
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.id;
```

> I want to find all
>   the tasks which don't have messages with `author_id` equal to
>   `tasks.seller_id` (or don't have messages at all).

One very straight-forward way to get the reverse of the top query is to use it as a sub-query for `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT tasks.id
FROM tasks
WHERE
  tasks.id NOT IN
  (
    SELECT t.id
    FROM tasks AS t
    INNER JOIN chats AS c ON c.task_id = t.id
    INNER JOIN messages AS m 
        ON  m.chat_id = c.id
        AND t.seller_id = m.author_id
  )
;
```

[Here is SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1242e/12).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find all the tasks which doesn't have messages with author_id equals to tasks.seller_id (or don't have messages at all).

Here's how I would write it:

```
SELECT t.id  
FROM tasks AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN chats AS c ON c.task_id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages AS m ON m.chat_id = c.id
    AND t.seller_id = m.author_id
WHERE m.chat_id IS NULL
ORDER BY t.id;
```

> I want to find the reverse, tasks with at least one message with author_id equals to seller_id.

Here's how I would write it:

```
SELECT t.id
     , COUNT(*) AS sellerMessages  
FROM tasks AS t
INNER JOIN chats AS c ON c.task_id = t.id
INNER JOIN messages AS m ON m.chat_id = c.id
    AND t.seller_id = m.author_id
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING sellerMessages > 0
ORDER BY t.id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and effort, it seems something isn't right so I'll past a complete MCVE.